# Beautifulsoup HTML table parsing--only able to get the last row?

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have a simple HTML table to parse but somehow Beautifulsoup is only able to get me results from the last row. I'm wondering if anyone would take a look at that and see what's wrong. So I already created the rows object from the HTML table:

```
 <table class='participants-table'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th data-field="name" class="sort-direction-toggle name">Name</th>
          <th data-field="type" class="sort-direction-toggle type active-sort asc">Type</th>
          <th data-field="sector" class="sort-direction-toggle sector">Sector</th>
          <th data-field="country" class="sort-direction-toggle country">Country</th>
          <th data-field="joined_on" class="sort-direction-toggle joined-on">Joined On</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class='name'><a href="/what-is-gc/participants/4479-Grontmij">Grontmij</a></th>
          <td class='type'>Company</td>
          <td class='sector'>General Industrials</td>
          <td class='country'>Netherlands</td>
          <td class='joined-on'>2000-09-20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class='name'><a href="/what-is-gc/participants/4492-Groupe-Bial">Groupe Bial</a></th>
          <td class='type'>Company</td>
          <td class='sector'>Pharmaceuticals &amp; Biotechnology</td>
          <td class='country'>Portugal</td>
          <td class='joined-on'>2004-02-19</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

I use the following codes to get the rows:

```
table=soup.find_all("table", class_="participants-table")
table1=table[0]
rows=table1.find_all('tr')
rows=rows[1:]
```

This gets:

```
rows=[<tr>
 <th class="name"><a href="/what-is-gc/participants/4479-Grontmij">Grontmij</a></th>
 <td class="type">Company</td>
 <td class="sector">General Industrials</td>
 <td class="country">Netherlands</td>
 <td class="joined-on">2000-09-20</td>
 </tr>, <tr>
 <th class="name"><a href="/what-is-gc/participants/4492-Groupe-Bial">Groupe Bial</a></th>
 <td class="type">Company</td>
 <td class="sector">Pharmaceuticals &amp; Biotechnology</td>
 <td class="country">Portugal</td>
 <td class="joined-on">2004-02-19</td>
 </tr>]
```

As expected, it looks like. However, if I continue:

```
for row in rows:
    cells = row.find_all('th')
```

I'm only able to get the last entry!

```
cells=[<th class="name"><a href="/what-is-gc/participants/4492-Groupe-Bial">Groupe Bial</a></th>]
```

What is going on? This is my first time using beautifulsoup, and what I'd like to do is to export this table into CSV. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: How is `rows` defined?

Comment: Thanks! More detail provided about the table & codes.

Comment: It's doing exactly what your asking it to do. Are you trying to get all the `td`'s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extend if you want all the th tags in a single list, you just keep reassigning `cells = row.find_all('th')` so when your print cells outside the loop you will only see what it was last assigned to i.e the last th in the last tr:

```
cells = []
for row in rows:
 cells.extend(row.find_all('th'))
```

Also since there is only one table you can just use *find*:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

table = soup.find("table", class_="participants-table")
```

If you want to skip the thead row you can use a *css selector*:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

rows = soup.select("table.participants-table  thead ~ tr")

cells = [tr.th for tr in rows]
print(cells)
```

cells will give you:

```
[<th class="name"><a href="/what-is-gc/participants/4479-Grontmij">Grontmij</a></th>, <th class="name"><a href="/what-is-gc/participants/4492-Groupe-Bial">Groupe Bial</a></th>]
```

To write the whole table to csv:

```
import csv

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

rows = soup.select("table.participants-table tr")

with open("data.csv", "w") as out:
    wr = csv.writer(out)
    wr.writerow([th.text for th in rows[0].find_all("th")] + ["URL"])

    for row in rows[1:]:
        wr.writerow([tag.text for tag in row.find_all()] + [row.th.a["href"]])
```

which for you sample will give you:

```
Name,Type,Sector,Country,Joined On,URL
Grontmij,Company,General Industrials,Netherlands,2000-09-20,/what-is-gc/participants/4479-Grontmij
Groupe Bial,Company,Pharmaceuticals & Biotechnology,Portugal,2004-02-19,/what-is-gc/participants/4492-Groupe-Bial
```

Comment: Thanks! This gets it a lot closer to my goal! Actually what I'd like to do is to  export this table into a typical CSV format with the "Name" and the html link as separate columns. Is there a way to do this with the "extend" method you just suggested? Thanks!

Comment: @AD233, so you basically want to recreate the table in a csv?

Comment: That is correct, except I'd like to extract the href link as a separate column. Thanks!

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for the help! This is quite fun indeed