# BeautifulSoup HTML scraping, how to get row after thead in tbody

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm interest in learning about scraping a website. now I learn how to scraping table on the website. I used BeautifulSoup.

I have a simple HTML table to parse but somehow Beautifulsoup I try to get row in tbody but always get word in "thead" ones. . I'm wondering if anyone would take a look at that and see what's wrong. So I already created the rows object from the HTML table:

```
<table id="companyTable" class="table table--zebra table-content-page width-block dataTable no-footer" role="grid" aria-describedby="companyTable_info" style="width: 868px;">
<thead>
    <tr role="row">
        <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 41px;">No</th>
        <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 224px;">Kode/Nama Perusahaan</th>
        <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 267px;">Nama</th>
        <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 187px;">Tanggal Pencatatan</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td class="text-center">1</td>
        <td class="text-center">AALI</td>
        <td><a href="/perusahaan-tercatat/profil-perusahaan-tercatat/detail-profile-perusahaan-tercatat/?kodeEmiten=AALI">Astra Agro Lestari Tbk</a></td>
        <td>09 Des 1997</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
        <td class="text-center">2</td>
        <td class="text-center">ABBA</td>
        <td><a href="/perusahaan-tercatat/profil-perusahaan-tercatat/detail-profile-perusahaan-tercatat/?kodeEmiten=ABBA">Mahaka Media Tbk</a></td>
        <td>03 Apr 2002</td>
    </tr>
```

I'm really really sorry I've already read and tried this [Beautifulsoup HTML table parsing--only able to get the last row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753246/beautifulsoup-html-table-parsing-only-able-to-get-the-last-row?rq=1&newreg=ed7cd48d67134cd29c431ef47a1daad9) . but still, don't get it.. and get '[ ]' at output.

here's the link that I want to scrape it. : https://www.idx.co.id/perusahaan-tercatat/profil-perusahaan-tercatat/

I want to get this row.

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td class="text-center">1</td>
        <td class="text-center">AALI</td>
        <td><a href="/perusahaan-tercatat/profil-perusahaan-tercatat/detail-profile-perusahaan-tercatat/?kodeEmiten=AALI">Astra Agro Lestari Tbk</a></td>
        <td>09 Des 1997</td>
    </tr>
```

I try to get it but always get word in "thead" ones.

here's my code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
url = 'https://www.idx.co.id/perusahaan-tercatat/profil-perusahaan-tercatat/'
uClient = uReq(url)
pageHtml = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
pageSoup = soup(pageHtml, "html.parser")
table = pageSoup.findAll('table', id = "companyTable")
table = table[0]
for row in table.findAll('tr'):
for cell in row.findAll('th'):
print(cell.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need the first `tr` in the `tbody` tag. So I'd use this:

```
first_row = s.find('tbody').find('tr')
```

Where `s` is the soup in my case. Here's an example:

```
>>> html = """<table id="companyTable" class="table table--zebra table-content-page width-block dataTable no-footer" role="grid" aria-describedby="companyTable_info" style="width: 868px;">
... <thead>
...     <tr role="row">
...         <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 41px;">No</th>
...         <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 224px;">Kode/Nama Perusahaan</th>
...         <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 267px;">Nama</th>
...         <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 187px;">Tanggal Pencatatan</th>
...     </tr>
... </thead>
... <tbody>
...     <tr role="row" class="odd">
...         <td class="text-center">1</td>
...         <td class="text-center">AALI</td>
...         <td><a href="/perusahaan-tercatat/profil-perusahaan-tercatat/detail-profile-perusahaan-tercatat/?kodeEmiten=AALI">Astra Agro Lestari Tbk</a></td>
...         <td>09 Des 1997</td>
...     </tr>
...     <tr role="row" class="even">
...         <td class="text-center">2</td>
...         <td class="text-center">ABBA</td>
...         <td><a href="/perusahaan-tercatat/profil-perusahaan-tercatat/detail-profile-perusahaan-tercatat/?kodeEmiten=ABBA">Mahaka Media Tbk</a></td>
...         <td>03 Apr 2002</td>
...     </tr>
... """
>>> s = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> first_row = s.find('tbody').find('tr')
>>> first_row
<tr class="odd" role="row">
<td class="text-center">1</td>
<td class="text-center">AALI</td>
<td><a href="/perusahaan-tercatat/profil-perusahaan-tercatat/detail-profile-perusahaan-tercatat/?kodeEmiten=AALI">Astra Agro Lestari Tbk</a></td>
<td>09 Des 1997</td>
</tr>
```

It works because `find` only returns the first element that matches

Answer (score -1):

#### Solving the problem

If I understood it right, you just want to get the table data from [this site](https://www.idx.co.id/perusahaan-tercatat/profil-perusahaan-tercatat/). However, inspecting the site and analyzing the requests and responses using the [Google Network tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network), I just found out that the site is using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) and fills the table using JS, with the responses from [this request](https://www.idx.co.id/umbraco/Surface/Helper/GetEmiten?emitenType=s).

In other words, you could just have made

```py
import requests

url = "https://www.idx.co.id/umbraco/Surface/Helper/GetEmiten?emitenType=s"
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.json())
```

#### What you should learn from this

Inspecting the page elements and requests/responses in order to know what is the easiest way to get the data. The tool I suggest is the [Chrome Devtools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools), but you may use the browser that fits you the best.

Comment: thankyou for you're replying. but I think I make a mistake that I need scraping but I write "parsing". im so sorry.. :( but, I would love to learn parsing too :)

Comment: You could re-write your question so we can help you.

Comment: you can use pd.DataFrame on json returned but note this json only returns two columns and misses the last.

Comment: Probably the remaining data is in another request. But the point here is really that: the data he is searching for is not on the returned page, but on another request.