# how to get row after "thead" in tbody in BeautifulSoup HTML scraping?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm interest in learning about scraping a website. now I learn how to scraping table on the website and I used BeautifulSoup.

I have a simple HTML table to parse but somehow Beautifulsoup I try to get row in tbody but always get word in "thead" ones.. I'm wondering if anyone would take a look at that and see what's wrong. So I already created the rows object from the HTML table:

```
<table id="companyTable" class="table table--zebra table-content-page width-block dataTable no-footer" role="grid" aria-describedby="companyTable_info" style="width: 868px;">
<thead>
    <tr role="row">
        <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 41px;">No</th>
        <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 224px;">Kode/Nama Perusahaan</th>
        <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 267px;">Nama</th>
        <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 187px;">Tanggal Pencatatan</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td class="text-center">1</td>
        <td class="text-center">AALI</td>
        <td><a href="/perusahaan-tercatat/profil-perusahaan-tercatat/detail-profile-perusahaan-tercatat/?kodeEmiten=AALI">Astra Agro Lestari Tbk</a></td>
        <td>09 Des 1997</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
        <td class="text-center">2</td>
        <td class="text-center">ABBA</td>
        <td><a href="/perusahaan-tercatat/profil-perusahaan-tercatat/detail-profile-perusahaan-tercatat/?kodeEmiten=ABBA">Mahaka Media Tbk</a></td>
        <td>03 Apr 2002</td>
    </tr>
```

I'm really really sorry I've already read and tried this [Beautifulsoup HTML table parsing--only able to get the last row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753246/beautifulsoup-html-table-parsing-only-able-to-get-the-last-row?rq=1&newreg=ed7cd48d67134cd29c431ef47a1daad9) but still, don't get it.. and get '[ ]' at output.

here's the link that I want to scrape it. : https://www.idx.co.id/perusahaan-tercatat/profil-perusahaan-tercatat/

I want to get this row.

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td class="text-center">1</td>
        <td class="text-center">AALI</td>
        <td><a href="/perusahaan-tercatat/profil-perusahaan-tercatat/detail-profile-perusahaan-tercatat/?kodeEmiten=AALI">Astra Agro Lestari Tbk</a></td>
        <td>09 Des 1997</td>
    </tr>
```

I try to get it but always get word in "thead" ones.

here's my code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
url = 'https://www.idx.co.id/perusahaan-tercatat/profil-perusahaan-tercatat/'
uClient = uReq(url)
pageHtml = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
pageSoup = soup(pageHtml, "html.parser")
table = pageSoup.findAll('table', id = "companyTable")
table = table[0]
for row in table.findAll('tr'):
for cell in row.findAll('th'):
print(cell.text)
```

Comment: I think the table body is generated dynamically using js. You will have to try with solutions using selenium - chrome headless options.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.idx.co.id/perusahaan-tercatat/profil-perusahaan-tercatat/'

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,features='html.parser')

table = soup.find('tb') 
rows = table.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

Returns:

```
<tr class="odd" role="row"><td class="text-center">1</td><td class="text-center">AALI</td><td><a href="/perusahaan-tercatat/profil-perusahaan-tercatat/detail-profile-perusahaan-tercatat/?kodeEmiten=AALI">Astra Agro Lestari Tbk</a></td><td>09 Des 1997</td></tr>
<tr class="even" role="row"><td class="text-center">2</td><td class="text-center">ABBA</td><td><a href="/perusahaan-tercatat/profil-perusahaan-tercatat/detail-profile-perusahaan-tercatat/?kodeEmiten=ABBA">Mahaka Media Tbk</a></td><td>03 Apr 2002</td></tr>
<tr class="odd" role="row"><td class="text-center">3</td><td class="text-center">ABDA</td><td><a href="/perusahaan-tercatat/profil-perusahaan-tercatat/detail-profile-perusahaan-tercatat/?kodeEmiten=ABDA">Asuransi Bina Dana Arta Tbk</a></td><td>06 Jul 1989</td></tr>
<tr class="even" role="row"><td class="text-center">4</td><td class="text-center">ABMM</td><td><a href="/perusahaan-tercatat/profil-perusahaan-tercatat/detail-profile-perusahaan-tercatat/?kodeEmiten=ABMM">ABM Investama Tbk</a></td><td>06 Des 2011</td></tr>
<tr class="odd" role="row"><td class="text-center">5</td><td class="text-center">ACES</td><td><a href="/perusahaan-tercatat/profil-perusahaan-tercatat/detail-profile-perusahaan-tercatat/?kodeEmiten=ACES">Ace Hardware Indonesia Tbk</a></td><td>06 Nov 2007</td></tr>
<tr class="even" role="row"><td class="text-center">6</td><td class="text-center">ACST</td><td><a href="/perusahaan-tercatat/profil-perusahaan-tercatat/detail-profile-perusahaan-tercatat/?kodeEmiten=ACST">PT Acset Indonusa Tbk.</a></td><td>24 Jun 2013</td></tr>
<tr class="odd" role="row"><td class="text-center">7</td><td class="text-center">ADES</td><td><a href="/perusahaan-tercatat/profil-perusahaan-tercatat/detail-profile-perusahaan-tercatat/?kodeEmiten=ADES">Akasha Wira International Tbk  Tbk</a></td><td>13 Jun 1994</td></tr>
<tr class="even" role="row"><td class="text-center">8</td><td class="text-center">ADHI</td><td><a href="/perusahaan-tercatat/profil-perusahaan-tercatat/detail-profile-perusahaan-tercatat/?kodeEmiten=ADHI">PT Adhi Karya (Persero) Tbk.</a></td><td>18 Mar 2004</td></tr>
<tr class="odd" role="row"><td class="text-center">9</td><td class="text-center">ADMF</td><td><a href="/perusahaan-tercatat/profil-perusahaan-tercatat/detail-profile-perusahaan-tercatat/?kodeEmiten=ADMF">Adira Dinamika Multi Finance Tbk</a></td><td>31 Mar 2004</td></tr>
<tr class="even" role="row"><td class="text-center">10</td><td class="text-center">ADMG</td><td><a href="/perusahaan-tercatat/profil-perusahaan-tercatat/detail-profile-perusahaan-tercatat/?kodeEmiten=ADMG">Polychem Indonesia Tbk</a></td><td>20 
Okt 1993</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, I would choose a different path. The data is available through XHR request, and will return more data, in json format, which you can convert to a table. Please accept the other solution as it directly answers your quesion, but I'm just providing complimentary/alternative way to pull the data.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://www.idx.co.id/umbraco/Surface/ListedCompany/GetCompanyProfiles'

payload = {
'draw': '1',
'columns[0][data]': 'KodeEmiten',
'columns[0][name]': '',
'columns[0][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[0][orderable]': 'false',
'columns[0][search][value]': '',
'columns[0][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[1][data]': 'KodeEmiten',
'columns[1][name]': '',
'columns[1][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[1][orderable]': 'false',
'columns[1][search][value]': '',
'columns[1][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[2][data]': 'NamaEmiten',
'columns[2][name]': '',
'columns[2][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[2][orderable]': 'false',
'columns[2][search][value]': '',
'columns[2][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[3][data]': 'TanggalPencatatan',
'columns[3][name]': '',
'columns[3][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[3][orderable]': 'false',
'columns[3][search][value]': '',
'columns[3][search][regex]': 'false',
'start': '0',
'length': '1000',
'search[value]': '',
'search[regex]': 'false'}

jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(jsonData['data'])
```

**Output:** *1st 5 rows

```
print (df.head(5).to_string())
                                              Alamat                                                BAE  DataID Divisi  EfekEmiten_EBA  EfekEmiten_ETF  EfekEmiten_Obligasi  EfekEmiten_SPEI  EfekEmiten_Saham                                  Email                           Fax JenisEmiten                                 KegiatanUsahaUtama KodeDivisi KodeEmiten                                               Logo NPKP                   NPWP                   NamaEmiten PapanPencatatan                        Sektor  Status                        SubSektor    TanggalPencatatan         Telepon                      Website  id
0  Jl Pulo Ayang Raya Blok OR No. 1  Kawasan Indu...  PT. Raya Saham Registrar (dulu bernama PT. Ris...       0   None           False           False                False            False              True              Investor@astra-agro.co.id  461-6655, 461-6677, 461-6688        None                             Agriculture Plantation       None       AALI  /Portals/0/StaticData/ListedCompanies/LogoEmit...        01.334.427.0-054.000       Astra Agro Lestari Tbk           UTAMA                   AGRICULTURE       0                       PLANTATION  1997-12-09T00:00:00       461-65-55  http://www.astra-agro.co.id   0
1  Sahid Office Boutique, Blok G Jl Jend Sudirman...                          PT. Adimitra Jasa Korpora       0   None           False           False                False            False              True                 corsec@mahakamedia.com                (021) 573 9210        None                               Media dan Percetakan       None       ABBA  /Portals/0/StaticData/ListedCompanies/LogoEmit...    0   01.609.052.4-017.000             Mahaka Media Tbk    PENGEMBANGAN  TRADE, SERVICES & INVESTMENT       0  ADVERTISING, PRINTING AND MEDIA  2002-04-03T00:00:00  (021) 573 9203          www.mahakamedia.com   0
2  Plaza Asia Lt. 27 Jl. Jend. Sudirman Kav. 59 J...                            PT. Raya Saham Registra       0   None           False           False                False            False              True                   contactus@abda.co.id                    5140 1698         None                                 Asuransi Kerugian        None       ABDA  /Portals/0/StaticData/ListedCompanies/LogoEmit...       01.362.014.1-054.000   Asuransi Bina Dana Arta Tbk    Pengembangan                       FINANCE       0                        INSURANCE  1989-07-06T00:00:00       5140 1688               www.abda.co.id   0
3  Gedung TMT 1 Lantai 18  Jl. Cilandak KKO No. 1...                               PT. Datindo Entrycom       0   None           False           False                False            False              True  corporate-secretary@abm-investama.com                  021-29976768        None  berupa jasa penyewaan namun tidak terbatas pad...       None       ABMM  /Portals/0/StaticData/ListedCompanies/LogoEmit...    0   02.504.191.4-017.000            ABM Investama Tbk           UTAMA  TRADE, SERVICES & INVESTMENT       0               INVESTMENT COMPANY  2011-12-06T00:00:00    021-29976767        www.abm-investama.com   0
4  Gedung Kawan Lama Lantai 5  Jl. Puri Kencana N...                                  PT. EDI Indonesia       0   None           False           False                False            False              True                 toto@acehardware.co.id                 021 - 5824022        None                                        Perdagangan       None       ACES  /Portals/0/StaticData/ListedCompanies/LogoEmit...        01.721.123.6-054.000   Ace Hardware Indonesia Tbk           UTAMA  TRADE, SERVICES & INVESTMENT       0                     RETAIL TRADE  2007-11-06T00:00:00   021 - 5822222        www.acehardware.co.id   0
```